# Why is BehaviorSubject<number | undefined> | async evaluating to null?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a `BehaviorSubject` that is typed to emit either `number | undefined`:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  indentation$ = new BehaviorSubject<number | undefined>(undefined)
  ...
}
```

I need to pass the emissions from this to a property that accepts either `number | undefined`. When connect it into the template though, it complains that it cannot accept `null`:

```html
<my-other-component indent="indentation$ | async"> 
<!-- 
         Type 'number | null | undefined' is not 
         assignable to type 'number | undefined' 
-->
</my-other-component>
```

#### The error goes away with a bang!

```html
<my-other-component indent="(indentation$ | async)!"> 
</my-other-component>
```

#### Where is the null value coming from?

Why would the template think that `indentation$ | async` might ever be null? It's not defined that way in the constructor so where's the gap in my understanding of how all this works?

Comment: From [the `async` pipe](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9e6538c4ba6fc4aeba22d70216c689dcf36a73ec/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L103) itself. The `transform` method's return type is `T | null`. By inference, the type returned by your async pipe is indeed number | undefined (from your type declaration) | null from async pipe.

Comment: I was hoping the angular team had described this in their [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) but this info seems nowhere to be found

Comment: Thanks both - @OctavianMărculescu would you like to post that as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Behavior subject used to have an initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the `async` pipe](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9e6538c4ba6fc4aeba22d70216c689dcf36a73ec/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L103) itself. The transform method's return type is `T | null`. By inference, the type returned by your `async` pipe is indeed `number | undefined` (from your type declaration) `| null` from the `async` pipe.